# Finding middle element of vector using iterator - C++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have two questions.

**First question**

I am reading about **iterators** in `C++` from `C++ primer 5th edition` book. In one of the code examples in this book, it is given that the following code snippet will find the middle element in the vector `vi`

```
auto mid = vi.begin() + vi.size() / 2;
```

Now I want to ask, why `vi.begin()` is added in `vi.size()` ? Wouldn't `vi.size()/2` be enough to find the middle element in vector `vi` ?

**Second Question**

```
auto mid = vi.begin() + vi.size() / 2;
```

In this code snippet, if I add parentheses around `vi.begin() + vi.size()` like this:

```
auto mid = (vi.begin() + vi.size()) / 2;
```

It throws error that `no "/" operator matches these operands...`

Why does it throws this error? I ask this because logically this expression `vi.begin() + vi.size()` should be calculated first and the result should get divided by `2`.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: `vi.begin()` gives an iterator to start of the vector. `vi.size()` gives the count of the elements (integer). When you add an integer to an iterator, the iterator moves forward by that many elements. Here you move forward by half the total number of elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expression `vi.begin() + vi.size()` results in an iterator which has been incremented `vi.size()` times, and iterators do not have an `operator/`.

The reason the first snippet works is that [the operator precedence rules of C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) mandates that `vi.size() / 2` is calculated first, then the result of this (an integer) is added to `vi.begin()` thus incrementing the iterator by the specified amount.

That is, the underlying misunderstanding is that `vi.begin() + vi.size() / 2` is not equivalent to `(vi.begin() + vi.size()) / 2`, but to `vi.begin() + (vi.size() / 2)`.

Comment: Well, in an expression `auto mid = vi.begin() + vi.size() / 2;`, the division (`vi.size() / 2`) will be done **prior** to the addition, as you suggest, due to operator precedence. So, it will return an iterator which has been incremented `vi.size() / 2` times.

Comment: if iterators don't have `/` operator then why does `auto mid = vi.begin() + vi.size() / 2;` works but `auto mid = (vi.begin() + vi.size()) / 2;` doesn't.

Comment: @Nick because `vi.size()` doesn't return an iterator, it returns a number.

Answer (score 2):

Using the code:

```
auto mid = vi.begin() + vi.size() / 2;
```

Makes `mid` an iterator to the middle element.

```
auto mid = (vi.begin() + vi.size()) / 2;
```

Does not make sense since iterators do not implement division.

The code `vi.begin() + vi.size()` returns an iterator to the past-the-end element (`v.end()`), which should not be divided by 2.